# Issues with mysqldump after upgrade 5.5 -> 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysqldump, logs, binlog

A few months ago I updated a MySQL setup from 5.5 to 5.6. Since then I've been having problems with a script that I use to dump the various databases so that I can back them up.

The script is a short piece of perl that gets a list of all databases and then calls `mysqldump` for each as follows:

```
mysqldump -udb_account -pdb_pw -hserver.com --single-transaction --flush-logs 
   --routines --triggers --quick $fn 2> $fn.err | gzip > $fn.mysql.gz
```

Issue: many of these databases have hundreds of tables (ever increasing). For these larger dbs the `mysqldump` command often exits after only a single table. *If I run the command from a terminal session it executes correctly.* (typically it runs as a cron job 1x/wk)

The `.err` file contains no messages. Neither does the `server.err` file in the MySQL root dir.

Note: this script had been running fine on MySQL 5.5 for several years. This problem started happening when I upgraded to 5.6.

Also: the `--flush-logs` portion isn't working. The mysql_bin folder has never been emptied since this system was brought online.

One variable that I haven't controlled for yet: when run as a CRON job the script forks 3 processes at a time. When I test the command in a term session I'm only doing one at a time.

System in question:

- CentOS 6.4
- x64
- 64Gb RAM

Comment: Are you shure that your `mysqldump` bin use the 5.6 version instead of 5.5?

Comment: Yes. It's a new system all around.

Comment: Add `--verbose` to the `mysqldump` options and see what you get in the error logs. This option doesn't change the dump files, but it writes some progress information to STDERR.  You should, at a minimum, see what it is "trying" to do, written to the error logs.

Comment: I suggest start from disable --quick option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is just a misunderstanding

Using [**--flush-logs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_flush-logs) with mysqldump simply closes and opens all files handles against the following:

- Error Log
- Engine Logs (Redo Logs Flushed to disk)
- Relay Log (If Replication is setup)
- General Log (if Enabled)
- Slow Log (if Enabled)
- Binary Logs (if Enabled)
- See [MySQL Documentation under Bulletpoint #3 ([log_type] LOGS)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html)

In the case of binary logs, the current binary log is closed and a new binary log is open. In essence, it is the only log file that is numerically rotated For example, suppose you run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` and you see the binary log file names `mysql-bin.000027`. Running `FLUSH LOGS;` or `FLUSH BINARY LOGS;` would close `mysql-bin.000027` (which stops recording transactions to that file) and open `mysql-bin.000028` (which now records incoming transactions).

However, rotation does not imply automatic deletion.

There are two ways to clean up the binary logs

## DELETE ALL BINARY LOGS

If the DB Server is not used as MySQL Replication Master, then run

#### BINARY LOGGING IS ENABLED

```
mysql> RESET MASTER;
```

That will erase all binary logs and start with the first one (like `mysql-bin.000001`)

#### BINARY LOGGING IS NOT ENABLED

Simply go the the OS and run the delete command (`rm` for Linux,`del` for Windows)

## PURGE BINARY LOGS

If you want to keep binary logs from the last 48 hours, you run

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR;
```

mysqld will erase all binary logs older than 48 hours.

## AUTOMATIC PURGING

Simply set the following in my.cnf (or my.ini)

```
[mysqld]
expire_logs_days=2
```

Then, either restart mysqld or run the following as `root`

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days = 2;
```

That way, every manual or automatic flush of binary logs will delete logs older than 2 days.

Once [***expire_logs_days***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) is set, mysqldump will cleanup old logs every time it does  [**--flush-logs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_flush-logs).

Comment: I think biggest problem of author - "For these larger dbs the mysqldump command often exits after only a single table. If I run the command from a terminal session it executes correctly. (typically it runs as a cron job 1x/wk)". His Job fail without errors from cron script.

Comment: @a_vlad If no error spits out, something tells me someone must have erased some binary logs manually, which can damage mysqld's ability to perform log rotations. See my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151129/mysql-replication-purge-logs-giving-error/151155#151155 and the links to my other posts showing why.

Comment: we are talking about different - his dump not finished, nothing about binary logs