# MySQL replication: purge_logs giving error

Tags: mysql, replication, binlog

On a MySQL replication instance I have this error message:

```
[ERROR] MYSQL_BIN_LOG :: purge_logs Was called Expired with file / db-space-no-connected-cpa / DBMS / dxnc6sla / arch / not listed in the index .
```

Can you give me an idea about the solution? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

## ANALYSIS

When [log-bin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin) is enabled, MySQL will log completed SQL transactions into binary logs.

Binary Logs are maintained by a text file whose name would be the same as the binary log but have file extension of `.index`.

For example, say you had `log-bin=/mysqllogs/mysql-bin` and started mysqld.

There will be files placed in `/mysqllogs`

```
mysql-bin.000001
mysql-bin.index
```

The index file will contain the name of all the binary logs.

In this example, it would contain `mysql-bin.000001`

Over time, binary logs will accumulate and you will have something like this in `/mysqllogs`

```
mysql-bin.000001
mysql-bin.000002
mysql-bin.000003
mysql-bin.000004
mysql-bin.index
```

and `mysql-bin.index` will contain this

```
mysql-bin.000001
mysql-bin.000002
mysql-bin.000003
mysql-bin.000004
```

Based on the variables [**expire_logs_days**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) (if it is greater than 0) and [max_binlog_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size), mysqld will do its own rotation and expiring of binary logs.

If you do the following

```
cd /mysqllogs
rm -f mysql-bin.000001
rm -f mysql-bin.000002
```

this will disable mysqld's log rotation mechanism. Why ?

The `/mysqllogs` folder will have

```
mysql-bin.000003
mysql-bin.000004
mysql-bin.index
```

but the `mysql-bin.index` will still contain this

```
mysql-bin.000001
mysql-bin.000002
mysql-bin.000003
mysql-bin.000004
```

mysqld actively uses the index file to verify that every file in `/mysqlvar` listed in `mysql-bin.index` exists before doing any rotation or expiration.

Therefore, you should never let the OS delete binary logs. Let mysqld do it.

I wrote about this before

- `May 23, 2016` : [Error 1236 - "Could not find first log file name in binary log index file"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139131/error-1236-could-not-find-first-log-file-name-in-binary-log-index-file/139308#139308)
- `Apr 23, 2013` : [Is it safe to delete mysql-bin files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41050/is-it-safe-to-delete-mysql-bin-files/41054#41054)

## SOLUTION

Shutdown mysqld, edit your `.index` file so the contents matches the exist binary logs on disk, and start mysqld. I have suggested this before ([Mysql binlogs exists, show binary logs is empty](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87002/mysql-binlogs-exists-show-binary-logs-is-empty/87013#87013))

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!